# difference in validation of jQuery and pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, button

Below is the first statement

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-default valid">Validate!</button>
```

and it will go to jQuery statement like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#form1').on('click', '.valid', function () {....
```

Below is the second statement:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" onclick="validate();">Validate!</button>
```

and it will go to Javascript statement like:

```
function validate() {
   var regex = new regexp(......
```

**What is the difference between** the first and the second statement?

My opinion said it is same, just it is difference on how we code it. The function of the button are same. The button will submit all data to validate it. I just want some clarification on it. Is it right?

**Is it a must** to use "onclick" in button tag if we want to use jQuery and put "function a()" to replace "$(document).ready(function ..."?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: First is `jquery` way, 2nd is `javascript`, might I add `pure javascript` way through inline `html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the way they are written, there is not much difference in what they do. However, I do want to mention that **they would behave differently for a dynamically added button**.

For example, if the button were to be added on the page dynamically after the initial load, the 'onclick' attribute will still work as it is able to register the event listener.

On the other hand, if you use a jquery click function (Eg `$('button').on('click',function(){}`), adding the button dynamically will not register the event listener. In that case you have to use event delegation like

`$('someStaticParentDiv').on('click',"button",function(){})`

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is:

**JQuery style:**

```
$('#form1').on('click', '.valid', function () {...});
// for this jquery library is required
```

**JS Style:**

```
function validate() {...}
// No library is required as this is pure JS code
```